# Fetching clientside HTML Table data to server side PHP script on form submission

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

I've an html form with multiple elements. Now, in particular to which I want your attention are two dropboxes and beside that an "add" button.so, once the user makes selection from the dropdown and presses the "add" button, it'll add the data to a table and that table will show up just below those dropboxes.So, basically user can add multiple data through the dropdowns and see it in a table. Now, the problem arises when I want to retrieve the data from this table when the form gets submitted. I'm not sure if $_PHP[''] would be able to fetch the data from the table I created.

So, as an alternative I'm trying to pass the data using AJAX when form gets submitted! 
HTML:

```
<form name="input" id="formToSubmit" action="process-host.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    /* Form data goes here*/
<input type="button" class="submit" value="Submit Request" onclick="valField(this.form); "/>
```

valField() method validates 
and submits the form.

JS:

```
function valField(form)     //field validation for the form before submit

{
   /*Validation code goes here*/

      //if(validated){
     $("#formToSubmit").submit(function(e) {       //this.submit(function(e)){
             e.preventDefault();

        var  tableForNew = new Array();   //to store the infoDisplayTable data

        $('#infoDisplayTable1l tr').each(function() {
        tableForNew.push($(this).find("td:first").html());
        tableForNew.push($(this).find("td:second").html());
        });



        // Get all INPUT form data and organize as array
        var formData = $(this).serializeArray();

        // Encode with JSON
        var tableForNew1 = JSON.stringify(tableForNew);


        // Add to formData array
        formData.push({name: 'tableForNew', value: tableForNew1});




        // Submit with AJAX
        $.ajax({
            url: "./process-host.php",
            data: formData,
            type: 'post',
            success: function() {
              alert("BOOM! IT WORKED;");  
            }
        });



    });
```

On the server side, in *process-host.php*, 
`$tableForNew = json_decode($_POST['tableForNew']);`

This obviously isn't working out, so when I'm debugging with Firebug, I can see that it is not going inside the submit function. It just submits the form, without going through inside code! and thats why its not posting any table data to server and gives error notice **Undefined index: tableForNew** .

So, what can I do here to make it work? any suggestions?

Comment: You don't need to use AJAX for this. If you add fields to a form, they'll be sent when you submit the form. As far as the browser is concerned, there's no difference between elements in the initial source and elements that are added with Javascript.

Comment: So, how would I access the data thats in table then?? cause $_POST['infoDisplayTable1l'] is not gonna workout!

Comment: Put the data in hidden input fields of the form.

Comment: You don't get it, here the user would be able to insert infinite number of entries to the table, so the table is not static but,dynamic!So, i wouldn't know how many hidden input fields would I need!

Comment: If you type $("#formToSubmit") into you firebug javascript console and hit enter does it return an element or an empty array?

Comment: it returns the element, and it's not empty!

Comment: the thing is that even if I put **alert()** inside the submit() function, I don't see anything!

Comment: @Barmar you were absolutely right about using hidden fields! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, making AJAX call while submitting the form didn't workout for me after all, but I did succeed in fetching the data from HTML table on the server side somehow! The solution that worked for me now is adding hidden fields to the form.Basically I'm adding hidden `<input>` fields to form when user inputs values and presses "Add" button, so it's in "Add" button's onClick event handler! Here's how that function looks like,

```
function addData1(){

if($("#consumerDropDown").val() != "" && $("#authenticationTypeDropDown").val() != "")
{
    $("#infoDisplayTable1").show();
    $("#infoDisplayTable1").attr("disabled", false);

    $("#infoDisplayTable1").append("<tr><td >"+$("#consumerDropDown").val()+"</td><td>"+
            $("#authenticationTypeDropDown").val()+"</td></tr>");
            $("#tester").append("<input type='text' value='" +$("#consumerDropDown").val() + "----->"+$("#authenticationTypeDropDown").val() + "' name='dTable1"+ counter1+ "'>");

        counter1++;
}
else
{
    alert("Please make a valid selection from a drop-down before adding it to the list!");  
}}
```

Here,note that I've defined **counter1** as globel variable in JS file.**Tester** is id assigned to a `<div>` tag with attribute **display:none**. More on, I'm assigning **name** attribute of `<input>` tag dynamically(for example,here it'd be *dTable10, dTable11* etc.), so it'd be easier to access it on server side! 
 And finally just before submitting the form I'm passing that **counter1** variable to hidden field just like how I did it above, 
 `$("#tester").append("<input type='text' name='counter1' value='"+counter1+"'>"); form.submit();`

**Server side:**

```
    $counterA = intval($_POST['counter1']);

                for($i=0;$i<$counterA;$i++)
                {
                $createReq['comment'] .=  $_POST["dTable1"."{$i}"]."\n";
                }
```

Here basically I'm appending this values to a string variable. It's gonna loop through each item, and gonna append to the variable. 
So, this worked for me as a solution for now! But, I'd have been more satisfied if the AJAX call would had worked while submitting the form(what I was trying to do before)!

Answer (score 0):

When you use an inline onclick handler you need to return false or else the default action will be triggered (submitting the form).

However, the way you have this setup right now the valField function will just define the submit handler and return - which means that even if you return false you will have to click the button a second time to trigger the submit event, which will also fire the valField function and redefine the submit handler (inception!).

You should remove the onclick handler you have on button element, move the submit handler out of the valField function, and only do the ajax call if the form is valid.

Comment: Hey, So I tried doing as you said and I got the `$('form').submit(function())` function out of the **valField()** method and returned false for the submit button,so that it wouldn't submit the form when it pressed.

Comment: But, still the same problem exists, I can see in the Firebug while debugging that the code doesn't go through the inside **AJAX call function()** of the submit() method. It just comes to the method call and then executes couple of lines from **jq-ui** file and then just exits the submit() method. I don't understand why it doesn't go through the inside function, since technically everything seems correct here! Any ideas about this?

Comment: The ajax method is async so it is only setting up a function to be called on success. Try adding an error: function handler. Also, have you looked at the network activity in firebug (net tab) to see if the ajax request is firing?

Comment: Ok, I've put an error function, but as you said ,when I checked the **net** tab in the firebug, I am not seeing this ajax request getting fired! It's just not executing the code thats inside the submit() function!